# Error while calling class from Java Script

Tags: javascript

Java Script -

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}

 Var r =  Confirm("Are you sure, you want to send email");
 if (r==true)
{
    sforce.apex.execute("ContactsendEmail","sendEmail",{Email:"{!Contact.Email}"});
    alert("Contact Email " + {!Contact.Email});
    alert("Email Sent Successfully");
}
```

Class -

```
global  class ContactsendEmail {

webservice static void sendEmail(String Email)
    {
     Messaging.Singleemailmessage mail = new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();
    mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'surinder.b.singh@accenture.com'});
    mail.setReplyTo('noreply@privatebudget.com');
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Private Budget App');
    mail.setSubject('Private Budget records for ' + Date.today().month() + ' ' + Date.today().year());
    mail.setBccSender(false);
    mail.setUseSignature(false);
    mail.setPlainTextBody('This is a test');
    system.debug('@@@@ sendEmail - mail : ' + mail);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

Javascript code fires on a custom button on contact. I ma getting error like -
"A problem with Javascript on this button - Unexpected identifier"

Comment: try to remove alert and then try.

Comment: Hi Tusar, Still getting same error. Unexpected identifier.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive so you need e.g. `var r = confirm(...`.

Comment: Well I guess unrelated but, with lightning does it still makes sense to use connection.js and that too api version 15.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to change

```
var r =  confirm("Are you sure, you want to send email");
```

Notice the `var` and `confirm` as Javascript is case sensitive. Complete code for reference.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/connection.js")}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/40.0/apex.js")}

     var r =  confirm("Are you sure, you want to send email");
     if (r==true)
    {
        sforce.apex.execute("ContactsendEmail","sendEmail",{Email:"{!Contact.Email}"});

        alert("Email Sent Successfully");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes it was case sensitive thing issue